# Cannot install extension

Tags: wordpress, extension, payment-processor, error, moneris

Trying to add an extension, I get the following error:

```
Database Error Code: Column 'entity_id' cannot be null, 1048
Additional Details:
Array
(
    [callback] => Array
    (
        [0] => CRM_Core_Error
        [1] => handle
    )

[code] => -3
[message] => DB Error: constraint violation
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_managed (module, name, entity_type, entity_id) VALUES ('ca.civicrm.moneris','Moneris','PaymentProcessorType',(SELECT id FROM civicrm_payment_processor_type where name = 'Moneris')) [nativecode=1048 ** Column 'entity_id' cannot be null]
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => INSERT INTO civicrm_managed (module, name, entity_type, entity_id) VALUES ('ca.civicrm.moneris','Moneris','PaymentProcessorType',(SELECT id FROM civicrm_payment_processor_type where name = 'Moneris')) [nativecode=1048 ** Column 'entity_id' cannot be null]
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: constraint violation" code=-3 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT INTO civicrm_managed (module, name, entity_type, entity_id) VALUES ('ca.civicrm.moneris','Moneris','PaymentProcessorType',(SELECT id FROM civicrm_payment_processor_type where name = 'Moneris')) [nativecode=1048 ** Column 'entity_id' cannot be null]"]
)
```

Is my extension out of date, or is this fixable?

~ross

Answer (score 1):

The issue is -

you don't have a payment processor type - Moneris

value missing in this SQL : SELECT id FROM civicrm_payment_processor_type where name = 'Moneris'

try to setup a payment processor type first - that should fix the issue

which mean you need to install the payment processor "Moneris" first to fix the issue

thanks - I guess this helps !!!

Comment: this is the error I'm getting when I try to install the Moneris payment processor. And the error seems to specify that the extension has no entity_id specified. Which seems odd. I'll look at the code myself to add an entity_id.

Comment: This got me on the right track after all! Seems all it needed was an empty entry named 'Moneris' which I did manually in the DB. Wasn't in any documentation or readme, but whatever.